# calculating MTBF in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table, maintenance-plan, logistics

I'm trying to Calculate MTFB with what I have, which isn't much, using Excel.

| Date | Full Plate Number | Vehicle Type | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/2/2021 | 1234 ABC | TRAILER | OUT OF SERVICE |
| 1/3/2021 | 1234 ABC | TRAILER | OUT OF SERVICE |
| 1/4/2021 | 1234 ABC | TRAILER | OUT OF SERVICE |
| 1/5/2021 | 1234 ABC | TRAILER | DEPARTED |
| 1/6/2021 | 1234 ABC | TRAILER | DEPARTED |
| 1/7/2021 | 1234 ABC | TRAILER | DEPARTED |
| 1/9/2021 | 1234 ABC | TRAILER | DEPARTED |
| 1/10/2021 | 1234 ABC | TRAILER | OUT OF SERVICE |
| 1/11/2021 | 1234 ABC | TRAILER | OUT OF SERVICE |
| 1/12/2021 | 1234 ABC | TRAILER | OUT OF SERVICE |
| 1/13/2021 | 1234 ABC | TRAILER | OUT OF SERVICE |
| 1/14/2021 | 1234 ABC | TRAILER | OUT OF SERVICE |
| 1/16/2021 | 1234 ABC | TRAILER | OUT OF SERVICE |
| 1/17/2021 | 1234 ABC | TRAILER | OUT OF SERVICE |
| 1/18/2021 | 1234 ABC | TRAILER | DEPARTED |
| 1/19/2021 | 1234 ABC | TRAILER | DEPARTED |
| 1/20/2021 | 1234 ABC | TRAILER | DEPARTED |
| 1/21/2021 | 1234 ABC | TRAILER | OUT OF SERVICE |
| 1/23/2021 | 1234 ABC | TRAILER | OUT OF SERVICE |
| 1/24/2021 | 1234 ABC | TRAILER | OUT OF SERVICE |
| 1/25/2021 | 1234 ABC | TRAILER | DEPARTED |
| 1/26/2021 | 1234 ABC | TRAILER | DEPARTED |
| 1/27/2021 | 1234 ABC | TRAILER | DEPARTED |
| 1/28/2021 | 1234 ABC | TRAILER | DEPARTED |
| 1/30/2021 | 1234 ABC | TRAILER | DEPARTED |
| 1/31/2021 | 1234 ABC | TRAILER | DEPARTED |

How can I use what I have to calculate a reasonable MTBF for trailers in Jan?

thank you

Comment: which mtbf formula d u intend to apply? [btw, there is no reasonable MTBF, it is just MTBF.]

Comment: Total Operational Time/Number of Failures, given 1 failure per day

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_time_between_failures use a different definition.  I get (3 + 4) / 2 = 3.5 days . D u get the same number?